# Scanning and printing on same file via Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, printstream

What I am trying to do with this code:

1. Start by reading the text file "occupancy", which would be initialized with
   10 zeros.
2. Assign it to an array(guestsIn[]).
3. Get new data from keyboard input, and update array(guestsIn[]) with new values(Sometimes all of the values will be overwritten, sometimes not)
4. Overwrite the new Array on the file "occupancy" in the form of 10 int values.

This is the error message I get when I run this code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at occupancyProg.main(occupancyProg.java:18)
```

Ultimately, I am trying to use a single text file(containing only of 10 int values) for the Scanning and printing.
But I have no idea what the error message is telling me, and I do not know where my logic is flawed.

From what I understand

```
    PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream(new File("occupancy"));
```

is supposed to create a file "occupancy" because of the use of *new* in the statement, so I fixed the code to following in hopes of fixing possible issues in the overwriting process(by deleting the existing file and replacing it with a new one), but the same error message appeared.
Help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class occupancyProg {

public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("occupancy"));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream(new File("occupancy"));

    int guestsIn[] = new int[10];
    int whichRoom, numGuests;
        for (int roomNum= 0; roomNum<10; roomNum++) {
            guestsIn[roomNum] = diskScanner.nextInt(); 
            }

        do {
            System.out.print("Room Number: ");
            whichRoom = keyboard.nextInt();


            System.out.print("Number of Guests: ");
            numGuests = keyboard.nextInt();

            guestsIn[whichRoom]=numGuests;

            System.out.print("Do another? Y/N");

        } while(keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0) == 'Y');

        new File("occupancy").delete();

        for (int roomNum= 0; roomNum<10; roomNum++) {
        diskWriter.print("guestsIn[whichRoom] ");
         }
        keyboard.close();
        diskScanner.close();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to open the file for read and writing at the same time. Even though you don't write to the diskWriter until you've finished reading from the diskScanner, simply constructing the diskWriter will open the file for writing and truncate the file. The order should be:

- open diskScanner
- read from diskScanner
- close diskScanner
- open diskWriter
- write to diskWriter
- close diskWriter

There is no need for the delete as opening the same file for writing will replace it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("occupancy"));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int guestsIn[] = new int[10];
    int whichRoom, numGuests;
    for (int roomNum= 0; roomNum<10; roomNum++) {
        guestsIn[roomNum] = diskScanner.nextInt();
    }

    do {
        System.out.print("Room Number: ");
        whichRoom = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Number of Guests: ");
        numGuests = keyboard.nextInt();

        guestsIn[whichRoom]=numGuests;

        System.out.print("Do another? Y/N");
    } while(keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0) == 'Y');

    keyboard.close();
    diskScanner.close();

    PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream(new File("occupancy"));
    for (int roomNum= 0; roomNum<10; roomNum++) {
        diskWriter.print(guestsIn[roomNum]);
        diskWriter.print(' ');
    }
    diskWriter.close();
}
```